# What is the iOS equivalent to WPF's Grid with star sizing?

Tags: ios, wpf, grid, uistackview

In WPF, I can create a Grid with multiple column definitions where a single column can occupy the unused screen space with star sizing like so:

```
<Grid Height="50">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Column="0" Background="Red"/>
    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Background="Blue"/>
    <Grid Grid.Column="2" Background="Yellow"/>
    <Grid Grid.Column="3" Background="Pink"/>
    <Grid Grid.Column="4" Background="Green"/>
</Grid>
```

[image]

I need to replicate the same UI on iOS. I have looked into using UIStackView, but since I have less experience working with iOS, I'm not sure how to go about doing this. Is UIStackView the right choice or do I need to use another layout? How can this UI be replicated on iOS? Please note that this needs to be done programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1.  Drag a "Horizontal UIStackView" to your ViewController in IB, and set the Top, Left, Right and Height constraints.

Step2. Drag 5 UIViews in your StackViews, and set "Width" constraint to the 0th, 2nd, 3rd and 4th views. So every child view will have a fixed width expect the second one.
That's it.

[image]